# How to show a PROMPT box in c# without javascript? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get a user's input using a prompt box, doing it on the server side without js, and then to use this input. 
how can i do that? Thanks!

Comment: @I4V, form in asp.net as an alternative for javascript prompt? How would that work?

Comment: @walther At least, OP can get user inputs with postbacks

Comment: @I4V, sure, he could use silverlight/... as well for data input, but how does it answer his question? "Show a prompt box without js"? It's not a prompt box if you create a separate webform and redirect to it. It feels and looks very different. I guess he already knows of such possibilities, that's the basics of any asp.net app... Create forms, get user input and do stuff.

Comment: Try this code at server side

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"prompt","prompt('Enter your message here.')", true);

Answer (score 1):

Let me put it this way:

Whatever user does - it happens on the CLIENT side. You can't show a prompt box without client-side technology like javascript. Your C# can't trigger anything on user's computer. Could you imagine what would it be like if it was possible? Asp.net sites taking control of your pcs?

So no, you can't do this without javascript, it doesn't make sense.